# запрос размерности списка

Tags: c#, .net

как запросить размерность списка у пользователя.

```
int value = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        List<int> list = new List<int>(value);
```

Так не работает.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Введите целое, положительное значение: ");
        int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        List<int> list = new List<int>(number);

        if (number < 0)
            throw new Exception("Введены не корректные данные");

        Random generator = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            list[i] = generator.Next(-99, 99);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
        {
            if (list[j] < 0)
                list[j] = 777;
            Console.Write(list[j] + " ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: А что не работает? Значение в `value` не получили или размер списка не тот?

Comment: после генерации и еще одного условия задачи ничего не выводится

Comment: @gil9red делал то же самое с массивом - работает, а со списком нет

Comment: параметр в конструкторе списка - это capacity - количество элементов, которые можно положить в список без дополнительного выделения памяти. То есть, сами элементы все равно надо добавлять с помощью Add

Comment: @Grundy Мне про это уже рассказали, я не знаю как это реализовать...

Comment: @Student, что реализовать?

Comment: @Grundy как добавить эти элементы, как использовать capacity

Comment: @Student, я же написал выше: _сами элементы все равно надо добавлять с помощью [Add](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=netframework-4.8)_

Comment: @Student _после генерации и еще одного условия задачи ничего не выводится_ Добавь в вопрос код, как ты это делаешь

Comment: @Grundy добавил

Comment: Вам ведь сказали `То есть, сами элементы все равно надо добавлять с помощью Add`, а вы упорно делаете `list[i] = generator.Next(-99, 99);`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я сделал это, все равно не выводит

Comment: у меня циклы не выполняются

Comment: Наверно потому, что у вас 0 объектов в списке и `list.Count;` выдает вам 0. Замените его на `number`.

Comment: Спасибо, решил!